# Change representation of array in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, propertygrid

The last property is an array of structures. I achieve correct representation by overriding the `ToString` of structures, but it is impossible to override the `ToString` of an array. I try to use `TypeConverter` it works but the property becomes non-expandable.

This is `TypeConverter`:

```
Public Class StringViewArrayViewConverter
    Inherits CollectionConverter

#Region "Public Methods"

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                                    culture As CultureInfo,
                                                    value As Object,
                                                    destinationType As Type) As Object
        If TypeOf value Is dpStringView() AndAlso destinationType.Equals(GetType(String)) Then
            Return FormatNumber(CType(value, dpStringView()).Length, 0)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

That used in a next way:

```
<Category(CategoryInfo)>
<DisplayName("Придатний")>
<TypeConverter(GetType(StringViewArrayViewConverter))>
Public ReadOnly Property SuitabilityDescription As dpStringView()
    Get
        Return Array.ConvertAll(Suitability, Function(i) New dpStringView(GetEnumDescription(i)))
    End Get
End Property
```

The next picture illustrates `PropertyGrid` without `TypeConverter`.

[image]

Is it possible to replace `dpStrinViev[] Array` with some short conclusion from its contents (like "1 message, expand to see details") and leave the property expandable?

Thanks for any advice or examples in VB.NET or C#

Comment: How does your TypeConverter for the array looks like? Have you tried [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @Steeeve You're right, questions aren't described well, I already add the code of TypeConverter to the question. I tried to use ExpandableObjectConverter but it gives Length, LongLength, etc instead of array members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake: my `TypeConverter` inherits `CollectionConverter` instead `ArrayConverter`.